# how to integrate tf-idf in nusvc?

Tags: scikit-learn, svm

I am dealing with bag of visual words using sift then i want to integrate tf-idf and then feed it to the svm namely nusvc in scikit-learn found here http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.NuSVC.html#sklearn.svm.NuSVC. how can i do this? any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Read the scikit-learn documentation about pipelines:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/pipeline.html

to chain instances of the [TfidfTransformer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer.html) class and the NuSVC class.

Make sure that your input data is a 2D array or sparse matrix that meat the expectations of the TfidfTransformer class.

Comment: thanks . can i add standard scaler  http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html after tf idf to make the data more accurate?